# getting an UIImage from ProfilePictureView

Tags: facebook, uiimageview, xamarin, uiimage, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to get the UIImage from ProfilePictureView given in facebook sdk. the code displays the picture when i extracted the UIImageView and added to the main view controller. but when I try to get the UIImage out from the UIImageView I instantiated, then it gives me the default profile picture of facebook. Please help!

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
base.ViewDidLoad ();

// txt_fname.Text = _user.First_Name;
// txt_lname.Text = _user.Last_Name;
UIImageView y = new UIImageView();
UIImage image = new UIImage ();
// btn_photo.SetBackgroundImage (fb_profile, UIControlState.Normal);

    foreach (var x in fb_profile.Subviews) {
        if (x is UIImageView) {
            y = (UIImageView)x;

            btn_photo.SetBackgroundImage (y.Image, UIControlState.Normal);

        }
    }
View.AddSubview (y);
```

[image]

Comment: How many UIImageView objects are there is subviews? I would guess more than one and the last one happens to hold the default profile picture. Why not grab the image directly... graph.facebook.com/<user id>/picture

Comment: @combinatorial I put a breakpoint in to check how many UIImageViews are there. it only iterates once. therefore, guess there is only one of them. I certainly can do that. but I was wondering why this is happening.